# show 2 picture fom datebase php

Tags: php, mysql

My datebase has 2 tables [white/black] and in that tables will be pictures. I want to show that image in a pair. One picture from white table and one picture from black table. It is like Hot or Not scripts. My question is how to display that images, that after page refresh there will be other pair.

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("dvddb");
  $sql = "SELECT image FROM white WHERE id=1 //and image from black where id=1";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  mysql_close($link);

?>
```

i found this code to display picture from id. How to set thath query...

Comment: do you want to display like White1,Black1 white2,black2, .. ?

Comment: Yes.. like hot or not... :)

Comment: Use a query like "select * from black join white on black.id = white.id and black.id = 1". This is a pseudo query, you need to edit it to conform syntax

Comment: is there any relation between black & white tables ?

Comment: no.. there is no relations... @Tuim thanks for answer i will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your solution :)

```
$qry = mysql_qyery("select * from white");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
   $qry2 = mysql_query("select * from black where id = '".$row['id']."'");
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
   {
      echo $row['image'];
      echo $row2['image'];
   }
}
```

please let me know if you want any further guidance...

Comment: This could be a performance issue, please look into using a single query with a join. For this example it probably does not matter, but I wouldn't want to teach someone bad coding manners.

Comment: @tulim yah you are right.. If I wanted than I could also give a `join query` but I thought this query which I posted will be easy to understand and implement ...
this is the query which can be used for good performance

`select w.image as white_image,b.image as black_image from white w join black b on(w.id=b.id)`

Comment: @Tuim Do you think this is better solution ..
SELECT * FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name

Comment: I'd use something along the lines of 'select * from black join white on black.id = white.id and black.id = 1'

Comment: but what if image's field name is same in both the tables?? @tulim

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQL Joins for this

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)